# Add list of objects using AddRange alongwith modifying value in each object

Tags: c#, linq, addrange

I am fetching a list of objects from an api but sometimes one of the elements of each object in that list is fetched as null. If that is the case I want to manually add that element since I have that value.

This is what I have in mind.

```
var result = List<item>;
foreach(obj in objects)
{
    var items = //api call;
    result.AddRange(items.Select(t => t.Name ?? obj.Name));  //Something like this
}
return result;
```

I would prefer to use AddRange if possible but I'm open to other solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
var result = List<item>;
foreach(obj in objects)
{
    var items = //api call;
    var modified = items.Select(t=>{
      t.Name = obj.Name;
      return t; 
    });
    result.AddRange(modified); 
}
return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Alik, This works perfectly. Just instead of taking another variable I put the Select clause in the AddRange method. 

`result.AddRange(items.Select(t => {
    t.Name = obj.name;
    return t;
}`